# Window shell script return codes

Tags: windows, shell

Is there a standard set of return code for Window shell scripts (*.bat files)? I'm looking for something analogous to Linux exit codes, where 0==success and non-zero==failure.
I need a way to programmatically check if my shell script failed during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common practive is the sames as the Unix standard, so a return code (also called errorlevel in batch files) of 0 is success, whereas anything higher than 0 is an error.

There are a number of related gotchas to look for though - have a look at this guide:

[Batch Files - Errorlevels](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)

Answer (score 2):

0 for success and non-0 for failure is also the convention for Windows batch commands.  when a command fails it sets ERRORLEVEL which is a special variable that can be tested in batch files.

```
if errorlevel 1 goto failure
```

As long as you don't run another command, the errorlevel will carry through to the caller that ran the .bat file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the errorlevel value.

The help of the IF shell statement tells me the following:

```
IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command

  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Windows utilities return `0` on success and non-zero on error (through the ERRORLEVEL variable) like Linux apps do.  Unfortunately, there is no enforced, official "standard" and not every utility or script sets errorlevels.

If you have a script that you want to test the return status for, make sure that script exits using `EXIT /B ##` which causes the errorlevel to be set to `##`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```
[run an exe here]

IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    CALL :SSH_fail filename.sh %errorlevel%
)


:SSH_fail
    Email.exe "%mailTo%" "%mailProgram% - SSH Failure " "Body: errorlevel:%~2 file name: %~1"
goto cont
```

this way I know exactly what the errorlevel was. I think there can be up to like 250 errorlevels.